# COM Exception HRESULT: 0xC00D1325 in C# winForm

Tags: c#, exception, media-player, comexception, hresult

I have a code in C# WinForm  that should be able to read the list of songs from a `listBox` and then play each song with `windowsMediaPlayer`  (for some reasons I want to play the songs from the last item of the `listBox` to the first one ) .

here is the code I'm using :

```
            int count = listBox1.Items.Count-1;
            listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items[count];
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

and then when playing the first song ended I wanted to change the `url` like this :

```
  private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange_1(object sender, _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
        {

            if (count > 0)
            {
                count = count - 1;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listBox1.Items[count].ToString();
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();

            }
        }
    }
```

this code will play the first song . BUT at this line `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listBox1.Items[count].ToString();` I got `COM Exception ERROR` and WindowsMediaPlayer control didn't play the other songs in the list .

here is the ERROR details :

```
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
   Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D1325
   Source=Interop.WMPLib
   ErrorCode=-1072884955
   StackTrace:
   at WMPLib.IWMPPlayer4.set_URL(String pbstrURL)
   at AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.set_URL(String value)
   at Avaye_Malakooti_92.Form1.axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange_1(Object sender, _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e) in C:\Users\Novin Pendar\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\New folder\Avaye Malakooti 92\Avaye Malakooti 92\Form1.cs:line 459
   at AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.RaiseOnPlayStateChange(Object sender, _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
   at AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayerEventMulticaster.PlayStateChange(Int32 newState)
   InnerException:
```

[image: Here is the error]

Anybody have any Idea why did I get that error or how should I solve it ?
thanks for help .

Answer (score 2):

a simple google search for that HRESULT code specified this as the value:

```
0xC00D1325
NS_E_CURL_INVALIDCHAR
The URL contains one or more characters that are not valid.
```

So, it seems you aren't pointing your player at a valid url for the second song.

You can see a list of HRESULT codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx)

Comment: I corrected the `url` to a valid one But It still doesn't play the next song . the exception problem has been solved . but why `mediaPlayer` deosn't play other songs ?

Comment: i have no idea. that sounds like a good subject for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of not playing the other songs , by adding a `Timer` to my code like this :

```
 private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange_1(object sender, _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
                count = count - 1;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listBox1.Items[count].ToString();
                timer2.Enabled = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

and then put this code to my `Timer2_Tick` event :

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        timer2.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Hope this solution helps everyone who had the same problem as mine .

Comment: Indeed, COM errors are often caused by method calls from threads which are not the UI thread owning the components called. Using a Winform timer as you did relocated your call in the right thread.